# Not able to autowire javamailSender

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, jakarta-mail

While autowire javamailsender getting following error:

> Field javaMailSender in
>   com.frs.services.MailService.impl.MailServiceImpl required a bean of
>   type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not
>   be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:

```
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

```
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addMail(MailServiceDTO mailServiceDTO) throws MessagingException {
        logger.debug(LogMarker.ENTRY, "Send Email with Subject  Message  to Email Addresses ");

        Properties props = ((JavaMailSenderImpl) javaMailSender).getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

        message.setFrom(mailServiceDTO.getEmailFrom());
        message.setTo(mailServiceDTO.getEmailTo());
        message.setSubject("Text");
        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

Used Dependencies:

```
    <!-- Mail Dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide mail properties in config file

```
# configuration email
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=email
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

Or you will need to have your own bean in your config file

```
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setProtocol("SMTP");
        javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        javaMailSender.setPort(587);

        return javaMailSender;
    }
```